# DocuSignAPI Error Code INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT

Tags: docusignapi

Recieving an error Code when making a demo call using the rest api v2 with an an email configured as a prospect to a template. Can anyone please let me know why this is being returned and it seems to work fine when the request is with a test@email.com

errorDetails INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENTThe email address for one of the recipients is not valid.

Answering my question again - ive actually removed the email tag from the envelope request , this was causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign system does not know if it's actually a valid email address (it would have to do a test send to figure that out), the only validation that is done through the platform is on the actual format of the email address.

If it's not in the format `(at least one character)@something.something` then it will be flagged as an invalid email address.  Looks like you've figured this out on your own though.